# In what issue did Dragon/Dungeon magazine transition to 3.5e rules?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Dungeon and Dragon magazines have been around for quite a while, though I can't find an online source to tell when they made the switch to the 3.5 ruleset. Does anyone know?

Issue #364 of Dragon, and #155 of Dungeon were the breakpoints to 4e (when Wizards took over again), but where's the start point for the 3.5e era?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really mean 3.5e and not 3e, [Dragon #309](http://paizo.com/products/btpy7zvj) (War, Incursion) from July 2003 was the first D&D 3.5 issue.  For Dungeon it was [centennial issue #100](http://paizo.com/products/btpy7z77?Dungeon-Issue-100-with-Polyhedron-159), starring the dragon Flame and also the Incursion mini-plotline.

Comment: I was going to say 310-312 because I remembered that they were the Update Issues, but I think you're correct, since the character conversion article was in 309.

Comment: That's correct, 310-312 dwelled on the new 3.5e changes but 309 was the actual cutover.  (You can see on the cover pic at the link above it calls itself "First issue D&D 3.5".)