# Looking for lycanthropy-related accessories

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I've been planning to use lycanthropes as important characters (NPCs) in my next campaign (Pathfinder).

I'm looking for any relevant accessories (rules, adventures, magazine articles, blog posts) that can add either some useful rules (classes or prestige classes, feats, items), insights on interesting lycanthrope character builds or just provide inspiration for NPCs and encounters.

Any summary of existing lycanthropy-related rules spread around different sources is welcome too.

**Edit:** I'm looking for information on all werebeasts, there will be different factions, evil, neutral and good. I'd need 12 different werebeasts. Obviously it's all possible with the bestiary templates, but I'd like to go beyond that for some of the factions.

Comment: If you want a fun one, there is the were T-rex asked here a few weeks ago http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44795/14893 although there isn't any faction, etc information in it (make your own faction of Dinosaur Cultists [http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-prestige-classes/bastion-press/dinosaur-cultist]?)

Comment: I've seen the T-rex, but I need typical beasts. Also, the factions are designed, as they're tightly integrated to the storyline. I'm looking for flavor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paizo has published a bunch of Pathfinder products specific to lycanthropes especially around the Carrion Crown Adventure Path, since one chapter is entirely werewolf-themed.

- [Player Companion: Blood of the Moon](http://paizo.com/products/btpy91dq?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Blood-of-the-Moon) has a bunch of player info on them, including the "skinwalker" race that's more suitable for PC use than the monster template
- [Classic Horrors Revisited](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ban?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Classic-Horrors-Revisited) is a GM book that details a reimagination of werewolves and other classic "Hammer film" kind of monsters
- [Broken Moon](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8jtl?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-45-Broken-Moon), an adventure in the Carrion Crown Adventure Path, is all about werewolves and has an article in the back about them
- [Various third party products](http://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=werewolf&includeUnrated=true&what=products&f=brand%2FPathfinder%20Roleplaying%20Game&includeUnavailable=true&sort=0)/[more third party products](http://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=lycanthrope&includeUnrated=true&what=products&f=brand%2FPathfinder%20Roleplaying%20Game&includeUnavailable=true&sort=0), easily findable for searching "werewolf" in Pathfinder products at paizo.com
- [Prince of Wolves](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8g3n?Pathfinder-Tales-Prince-of-Wolves), the excellent Pathfinder Tales novel set in Golarion
- The [Lycanthrope section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope) of the d20PFSRD has some excerpts from Blood of the Moon and the [Lycanthrope section](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lycanthrope) of the Pathfinder Wiki has info and links to many sources

Comment: Now that's a cool collection. +1

Answer (score 5):

The single most important 3.5 resource for *my* werecreature-based stories that I keep returning to is the **November 2003 issue of Dragon Magazine**, which featured a long(ish) article titled *Animal Ancestry* (by Dean Poisso.) This article details various lycanthrope classes – from werebear through wereboar, wererat, and weretiger to werewolf –, as well as a few crucial feral feats and personality traits that I, as a DM, have found highly useful. Indeed, I've run more than one complete mini-campaigns using primarily this information. (It *is* 3.5 already, since [Dragon made the change in July 2003](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/in-what-issue-did-dragon-dungeon-magazine-transition-to-3-5e-rules).)

Nonetheless, @mxyzplk's list is awesome, and you'll find a lot more background info following his links, but I – quite subjectively – thought this one here deserves a mention.

Additionally, I'd recommend checking out all the (semi-)official, related material written for the Ravenloft setting as well (for example: [Van Richten's Guide to Werebeasts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560766336)). Most of it won't help much with the rules, having been written for earlier editions of D&D, but they really are inspiring, and have great fluff.