# Porting a WoD werewolf to Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, world-of-darkness, conversion

I've been playing WoD pen and paper for some time, but had to change my gaming group. Now I'm playing Pathfinder.

Thanks to my GM I'm allowed to play a kind of WoD werewolf. We have a concept of a Barbar / Oracle skinwalker, but the real problems starts with porting the auspices.

How can I port a werewolf to pathfinder? Experience-based answers would be best. I'm trying to take the spirit of a wolf but it is not really fitting.

Comment: On the comments for @Mu_ 's answer below you ask for ideas to port your WoD character's *Gifts* - could you edit your question to include your specific Gifts? (I feel I have the opposite of Mu_'s problem - I'm only vaguely familiar with Werewolf, but can probably recommend relevant Pathfinder Feats/Traits/ACFs to mimic specific Gifts, if you add a short description about what they thematically do)

Answer (score 10):

Actually, there is a d20 version of WoD. Montecook's World of Darkness.

I wouldn't usually recommend this book because I think it loses all the horror and themes of World of Darkness, and as such I doubt the contribution, but in this case it might help.

I suppose it's not fully compatible with Pathfinder, but I hope it can help for a start point.

Anyway, I don't recommend you to mimic so much WoD's werewolves, or, in general, any other game aspect into other games. You should note that every game has its themes and tones, and if you are too focused on translating exactly the other game aspects, you will lose one game flavour for a poor conversion of other game's character.

If you have to play Pathfinder, embrace Pathfinder and enjoy it!

Comment: Upvoted for Monte Cook. I think that MCWoD would be ideal for this guy — I think it keeps many of the themes of the World of Darkness that a Pathfinder game could bring out.

Comment: Upvoted for "each game is different, enjoy the game you're playing"

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to go is to use the official dnd 3.x / pathfinder rules to come up with a lycanthrope character that fits the system mechanically and doesn't break your new party's game.

You'll find a lot of actual, official resources mentioned in the answers for a previous question titled **[Looking for lycanthropy-related accessories](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45414/looking-for-lycanthropy-related-accessories/45455#45455)**. I think you should bring it to your DM's attention, and work together to create a build that fits their campaign.

I'd like to note that I think your question here seems to be a duplicate of that question, unless someone has come up with / can point you in their answer to a set of well-established and tested house-rules built especially for a WoD/d20 conversion.

Comment: If you follow this method, which I also recommend, auspices can be translated in a pure roleplaying fashion, you play the lycanthrope according to the auspice you like. Also, you can try to get the Feats that suits the auspice. In the end, the concept of Feats is very similar to the concept of Gift.

Answer (score 4):

I think the level is impossible to translate from a system that is level-less (ok, ranks are similar to levels, but rank is your maximum for gifts, does not determine your character power per se).

As for Auspices, once I was thinking that Auspice determined roles in the group, and I came with the following relation:

Ahroun -> Fighter

Galliard -> Bard

Philodox -> Paladin

Theurge -> Wizard/Cleric

Ragabash -> Rogue

But if you want my advice, I would focus on the character concept (see any of the World of Darkness core books). Once you have clear what defines the essence of your character it should be easy to build a character based upon the same principles.

Comment: thanks :) this helps! could you also give me some advice for the gifts?

Comment: Sorry, I only have a mild knowledge about the Pathfinder system. I would recommend you to read the feats and the spell lists for your chosen class to look for something similar to them. I'm sure that in most of the cases you will find something (i.e. the "Persuasion" Gift as "Persuasive" feat, or even a high diplomacy skill; the "Smell of Man" as "Animal Affinity", "Speech of the World" as "Far Casting" spell; and so on), and when not, you can speak with your DM to homebrew something.